# Where should I store my images for my RoR site?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html

I currently store my images on PhotoBucket.com and use image url's to access them in my RoR application. Is this bad, and should I be storing them in my assets folder directly in the app? Wondering if there are pros and cons to each.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself have used [imgur](https://imgur.com/) URL's when adding photos to my MVC Views. However as far as production goes I would likely advise to use copies of the photos on the server in which you have used for deployment -heroku, azure, your own custom web server. Instead of relying on the page to pull the photo from another web server, it wouldn't hurt to already have that photo available on *your* web server. If that makes sense. Its *right there* ... but like I said. If someone comments on this and says it really doesn't matter - store them in your file system on your server or use something else then that means its preferences. I tried to just tell you what I think and what I would do.

Happy coding.

Comment: Ya, that makes sense to me. Thanks for the input.

Comment: No problem. Good luck. There are tons of options.

Answer (score 1):

Store them in your git repository with all other static assets.

Later on as the site grows look into Cloudfront or another CDN to manage static assets.

Comment: Thanks, I likely will make the switch to Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to look at:

--

**Assets**

`assets` are the files your application relies on to run

They are the images used in your layout & views - which are basically *static* files; required for different parts of your app:

> The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or
>   compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write
>   these assets in other languages and pre-processors such as
>   CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

If you're looking to use images for the CSS in your application, you really need to store them in `app/images` - as this will give you all the perks of the **[`asset_pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)**, including:

- [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) & other [asset helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)
- [`asset precompilation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)
- Multi storage options

The bottom line is if you want your app to be structured correctly, you *need* to store your image assets in the `asset pipeline`. As they assets are semi dependencies, they need to be stored within the app's compilation process; which won't happen unless they're inside the asset pipeline

--

**Uploads**

If you're looking to allow users to `upload` files, you need to be able to handle the transfer of the files from the front-end to the back-end

> Although Rails *can* do this (using the [`File` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html)), you'll be
>   best using the likes of [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [`Carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

These allow you to store your uploads on third-party repositories, such as `s3` or `Dropbox`, the most important thing is they allow you to handle the transfer, ensuring the structure of the files is maintained correctly.

--

**Storage**

If you're looking to store the assets in some kind of CDN, you may wish to either use the [`asset_sync`](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem, or set up `cloudfront` or something.

The trick beauty of rails is you can change the asset host relatively simply:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.asset_host = "your_asset_host"
```

You can read more about [`config.asset_host` configuration here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)